# Generating a big XML file using PHP from data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysql-workbench

I have this XML file that is generated by PHP, but the amount of information it generates is small. Now I want to generate a one big XML file that will contain data from multiple tables which are associated with each other. But using the PHP to structure out the XML file is confusing because the SQL statement is getting very large. Is there any way to generate a big XMl File using PHP or any other tool?

```
$query = "SELECT institution_t.Name, institution_t.idColleges, campus_t.CampusName, campus_t.CampusAddress, campus_t.Lat, campus_t.Lng  FROM institution_t JOIN campus_t ON (campus_t.idColleges = institution_t.idColleges)";
```

This is just the SQL statement with two table I need to add 8 more tables which are associated with each other.

Comment: Is this a question? What do you actually need help with? Can you show some sample code?

Comment: My problem is that The SQL statement and the PHP code to generate the xml is getting really complicated, and i was wondering if there an easier way to generate one big xml file with PHP

Comment: i think that the size of XML is the smallest problem

Comment: No, the problem is that the PHP code and SQL statement for generating that XML file is getting too complicated and redundant, so I was wondering if there is a better way or a tool to generate XMl with data from multiple tables which have relationship with each others in some ways (foreign keys, associative tables).

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a view to encapsulate the information you need from the query, then it's just a simple single-table select to get the information.  I have no idea how your XML is supposed to be structured, so I'm afraid I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic "take a query and dump it out to XML" because it all depends on what you need. You using attributes? Nested elements? Whatever.

Have a look at the various PHP tools for handling XML, such as [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php).